# Is there any method to fetch and update the child table data with the help of parent id in one to many mapping concept using Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can we fetch and update child table through parent id in one to many concepts using springboot ?

Comment: Spring boot is not related to your requirement, it's an sql question and maybe spring data too. Add more details about your entities relation if you want to have an answer.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
In few words: Java ORM do it for you, the most popular is Hibernate